# How do I import Google sheets data as a usable json value?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest

How do I import data from a google sheet into usable JSON data? I don't want to just console.log it or insert it as a div element.

I want to be able to assign the csv file received from the get request to a variable and convert it into a JSON dictionary.

```
function loadData() {
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ3CoW5ktyMAa8YTdQc5hrh_z7jqCURxa3kqxjZTuLGZ-067Un7uryjv1F6Yt7AXHQrz7KUJf7ZRRWl/pub?output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      console.log(xmlhttp.response);
      return xmlhttp.response;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}

const csv = loadData()
console.log(loadData())
```

Currently, the data logs on the console but I am not sure how to turn it into usable data.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How do I import data from a google sheet into usable JSON data? I don't want to just console.log it or insert it as a div element.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: My issue is that the variable csv is currently "undefined" and not the same as the xmlhttp.response that is being logged to the console.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your showing script, the value is returned as a CSV data. So, I cannot understand `How do I import data from a google sheet into usable JSON data?`. Can you provide your expected values?

Comment: The expected values should be 
"County,Composted
Kings County,642873
Queens County,151964
New York County,2894434
etc..." A string like this one should be printed into the console twice

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer, could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: This is almost what I want, how would I go about making the Counties the keys for the dicitonary and the numerical values the values? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function loadData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ3CoW5ktyMAa8YTdQc5hrh_z7jqCURxa3kqxjZTuLGZ-067Un7uryjv1F6Yt7AXHQrz7KUJf7ZRRWl/pub?output=csv";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        resolve(xmlhttp.response);
      } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
        reject(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
      reject(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  });
}

async function sample() {
  // Retrieve CSV data.
  const csv = await loadData().catch(err => console.log(err));
  if (!csv) return;
  console.log(csv);

  // Convert CSV to JSON data.
  const [header, ...values] = csv.split("\n").map(r => r.split(","));
  const json = values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => {
    const v = c.trim();
    o[header[j]] = isNaN(v) ? v : Number(v);
    return o;
  }, {}));
  console.log(json)
}

sample();
```

- When you run this script, you can see the retrieved CSV data at the log of `console.log(csv)`. And also, you can see the converted JSON value at the log of `console.log(json)`.

  - About JSON data, unfortunately, I couldn't find your expected value as I mentioned in my comment. So, I prepared it by guessing your goal. If that was not your expected value, please provide your expected value. By this, I would like to modify it.

### Added:

About the following reply,

> I'm looking for the expected value to be as follows: { "Kings County": 642873 "Queens County": 151964 "New York County": 2894434 "Suffolk County": 0 etc... }

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function loadData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ3CoW5ktyMAa8YTdQc5hrh_z7jqCURxa3kqxjZTuLGZ-067Un7uryjv1F6Yt7AXHQrz7KUJf7ZRRWl/pub?output=csv";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        resolve(xmlhttp.response);
      } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
        reject(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
      reject(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  });
}

async function sample() {
  // Retrieve CSV data.
  const csv = await loadData().catch(err => console.log(err));
  if (!csv) return;
  console.log(csv);

  // Convert CSV to JSON data.
  const [, ...values] = csv.split("\n").map(r => r.split(","));
  const json = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a.trim()] = Number(b.trim()), o), {});
  console.log(json)
}

sample();
```

- In this case, the output values are returned as JSON data. In the case of JSON data, the order of property is not preserved. Please be careful about this.

Comment: This is almost what I want, how would I go about making the Counties the keys for the dicitonary and the numerical values the values?

Comment: @gooboys Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. As I have already mentioned in my comment and answer, I cannot know your expected output values. And from `This is almost what I want, how would I go about making the Counties the keys for the dicitonary and the numerical values the values?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value. So, can you provide your expected value as I have already mentioned in my answer? By this, I would like to modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thanks for replying again, I'm looking for the expected value to be as follows:
{
"Kings County": 642873
"Queens County": 151964
"New York County": 2894434
"Suffolk County": 0
etc...
}

Comment: @gooboys Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?